# How to use Quartz Scheduler in Grails?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using Grails 2.3.11 and i want do Quartz Scheduling in Grails Application.

for this, i added two libraries `quartz-all-2.1.1.jar` and `c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar` but when i am running project it gives this errors

```
DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] BasicResourcePool.attemptRefurbishResourceOnCheckin(1616) | A resource could not be refurbished on checkin. [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5d12d30f]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.' at line 1
 at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:324)
 at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishResourceOnCheckin(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:299)
 at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.attemptRefurbishResourceOnCheckin(BasicResourcePool.java:1606)
 at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$200(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
 at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1228)
 at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Comment: have you tried out the quartz plugin for grails? https://grails.org/plugin/quartz

Comment: Yeah i tried with quartz plugin also but it gives me same error ..

Comment: can you provide code of you quartz job?

Comment: Did you execute the DDL that's part of the quartz install?  The quartz plugin (or just using quartz) don't create the tables needed for you, as there are several, and you can put a prefix to keep them easily separable from your regular tables.  Look in the instructions for using quartz.

Comment: Without installing quartz plugin or those two jar, did the application throwing the same error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off logging **c3p0** connection pooling

Add this lines before **loading the connection pool(Before Start Scheduler)**

```
Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.MLog", "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog");
p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL", "OFF"); // Off or any other level
System.setProperties(p);
```